# CSS font sizes in Paint.NET

Tags: css, fonts

css:

```
.lnk { font-size:0.9em; color:#0000CC; font-family:Courier New; }
```

How do I get the equivalent of this in Paint.NET?

I stumbled upon this guide:

```
100% = 1.0em = 16px = 15pt
95% = 0.95em = 15px = 14pt
90% = 0.9em = 14px = 13pt
85% = 0.85em = 13px = 12pt
80% = 0.8em = 12px = 11pt
75% = 0.75em = 11px = 10pt
70% = 0.7em = 10px = 9pt
65% = 0.65em = 9px = 8pt
```

but it seems incorrect.

(kinda related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672989/default-web-font))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size corresponding to 1 em depends of the default font size for your document.

In theory, 0.9 em = 0.9 * default font-size (usually 12pt).

It seems well-explained here : http://www.thesug.org/blogs/kyles/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=22